# Java - File being read returns null

Tags: java, arrays, bufferedreader

Hi I am loading a file into my program and assigning each value (stored on a new line to a array) I cant seem to spot why the array holding the file content is null in each index.

```
    private void readAndProcessWords() {
    try {
        FileReader _fr = new FileReader(FILEPATH);
        BufferedReader textReader = new BufferedReader(_fr);

        int numLines = getNumLines(textReader);
        String[] words = new String[numLines];

        for(int i=0;i<numLines;i++){
            words[i] = textReader.readLine();
            System.out.println(words[i]);
        }
        //clears memory reserved for this buffered reader
        textReader.close();

    } catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

private int getNumLines(BufferedReader textReader) throws IOException{
    String line;
    int numLines =0;

    while((line = textReader.readLine()) != null){
        numLines++;
    }
    return numLines;    
}
}
```

Solution: add the below code above the loop to 'reset' the file reader

```
_fr = new FileReader(FILEPATH);
        textReader = new BufferedReader(_fr);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.  See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Use a debugger to trace execution.

Comment: What do think `while((line = textReader.readLine()) != null){` does?

Comment: i would state that you have already consumed your file with getNumeLines(), hence you are at end of file when starting to parse lines.

Comment: Consider using Guava and code similar to this: final URL resource = Resources.getResource("path/to/file.txt");
        final List<String> lines = Resources.readLines(resource, Charset.defaultCharset());

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest solution is to recreate your `Reader`, the issue is that calling `getNumLines()` moves the position in your BufferedReader to the end of file.

```
BufferedReader textReader = new BufferedReader(_fr);
int numLines = getNumLines(textReader); // <-- textReader is at EOF after this.
textReader.close();
textReader = new BufferedReader(_fr);
```

Comment: Thanks for everyone thoughts! the suggestion above is indeed causing the issue. I amended with question with the fix accounting for this. I needed to add a additional line to make a new file reader.

Comment: Just a reminder that when you close the textReader you probably want to do that in either a finally block or using try-with resources in Java 7 to clean up the resource properly in the case of an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reading your file *twice* to get the line count (which is slow, annoying, and will not work if the file changes between the two calls), read the lines into a variable-sized list:

```
private void readAndProcessWords() {
    try {
        FileReader _fr = new FileReader(FILEPATH);
        BufferedReader textReader = new BufferedReader(_fr);

        List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
        String line;
        while ((line = textReader.readLine()) != null) {
            words.add(line);
        }
        textReader.close();

        for (String word : words) {
            System.out.println(word);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Good news: this functionality [already exists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-), so you don't need to rewrite it.

```
private void readAndProcessWords() {
    try {
        List<String> words = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(FILEPATH));

        for (String word : words) {
            System.out.println(word);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since a buffered reader is an object you pass it as a reference to the `getNumLines()` not as a copy, so you end up getting a null when you `.readLine()` on the same buffered reader you sent to the `getNumLines()` because you have already run `.readLine()` to its limit.

After running `getNumLines()` close and reopen the document with a new buffered reader.

I also remember there being a `Mark()` and `Recall()` method for buffered reader in java that could also serve as a work around.

I think like.

```
        FileReader _fr = new FileReader(FILEPATH);
        BufferedReader textReader = new BufferedReader(_fr);


        textReader.Mark();


        int numLines = getNumLines(textReader);


        textReader.Recall();


        String[] words = new String[numLines];

        for(int i=0;i<numLines;i++)
        {
            words[i] = textReader.readLine();
            System.out.println(words[i]);
        }
        //clears memory reserved for this buffered reader
        textReader.close();
```